# Passing Values between JSP and Servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets, data-transfer

For my JSP page, I am asking the user to provide ratings for items in order to provide the user with recommendations for other items based on said ratings.

However, my Servlet is doing all the calculating and is taking in a CSV file that contains all the various items and ratings.

My question is if there is a way that I can take randomized values from the Servlet (aka random items) and present it on the JSP page before the user enters his or her ratings

I tried using getAttribute and setAttribute but the values keep showing as "null".

This is the JSP file:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@ page import ="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@ page import ="java.util.List"%>
<%@ page import ="java.util.Random"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Video Game Recommender</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>How would you rate the following games?</h2><br><br>

<form action = "InputServlet" method = "POST">
    <h4><%= request.getAttribute("item0") %></h4><br>
    <select name = "first_item">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
           <br />
     <h4><%= request.getAttribute("item1") %></h4><br>
        <select name = "second_item">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
           <br />
     <h4><%= request.getAttribute("item2") %></h4><br>
        <select name = "third_item">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
           <br />
     <h4><%= request.getAttribute("item3") %></h4><br>
        <select name = "fourth_item">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
           <br />
     <h4><%= request.getAttribute("item4") %></h4><br>
        <select name = "fifth_item">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
           <br />
     <h4><%= request.getAttribute("item5") %></h4><br>
        <select name = "sixth_item">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
           <br />
     <h4><%= request.getAttribute("item6") %></h4><br>
        <select name = "seventh_item">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
           <br />
     <h4><%= request.getAttribute("item7") %></h4><br>
        <select name = "eighth_item">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
           <br />
     <h4><%= request.getAttribute("item8") %></h4><br>
        <select name = "ninth_item">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
           <br />
     <h4><%= request.getAttribute("item9") %></h4><br>
        <select name = "tenth_item">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        <input type = "submit" value = "Submit"/>
     </form>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Here is the servlet:

```
 * Servlet implementation class InputServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/InputServlet")
public class InputServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public InputServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> item = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> user = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> itemCos = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> userCos = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

        ArrayList<String> userList = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> itemTitle = new ArrayList<String>();

        ArrayList<String> itemGrad = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> userGrad = new ArrayList<String>();


        ArrayList<String> ratedTitle = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> ratedID = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Integer> ratedNumber = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<String> done = new ArrayList<String>();

        ArrayList<Integer> ratedCos = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        String fileName = "/C:/Users/Family/Desktop/Programming/Masters Project/VideoGameMeta.csv";
        String line;

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

        String customer = "User";

        String answer = "<html><br>";


        int div = 0;
        int itemNext = 0;
        int userNext = 0;

        double meanAll = 0;

        while((line = input.readLine()) != null){
            String[] elems = line.split(",");
            list.add(new ArrayList<String>());
            list.get(div).add(elems[0]);
            list.get(div).add(elems[1]);
            list.get(div).add(elems[2]);
            list.get(div).add(elems[3]);
            if (!itemList.contains(elems[0])){
              itemList.add(elems[0]);
              item.add(new ArrayList<String>());
              item.get(itemNext).add(elems[0]);
              item.get(itemNext).add(elems[3]);
              item.get(itemNext).add("0");
              item.get(itemNext).add("0");
              itemNext++;
            }
            if (!userList.contains(elems[2])){
              user.add(new ArrayList<String>());
              userList.add(elems[2]);
              user.get(userNext).add(elems[2]);
              user.get(userNext).add("0");
              user.get(userNext).add("0");
              userNext++;
            }
            meanAll = meanAll + Double.valueOf(elems[1]);
            div++;
         }
        input.close();

         user.add(new ArrayList<String>()); 

         userList.add("User");
         user.get(userNext).add("User");
         user.get(userNext).add("0");
         user.get(userNext).add("0");
         userNext++;

         int count = 0;

         while (count < 10){
            Random rand = new Random();
            int random = rand.nextInt(itemList.size()) + 1;
            String current = item.get(random).get(1);
            String id = item.get(random).get(0);
            if (!ratedTitle.contains(current)){
               ratedTitle.add(current);
               ratedID.add(id);
               count++;
            }
         }

         request.setAttribute("item0", ratedTitle.get(0));
         request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
         request.setAttribute("item1", ratedTitle.get(1));
         request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
         request.setAttribute("item2", ratedTitle.get(2));
         request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
         request.setAttribute("item3", ratedTitle.get(3));
         request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
         request.setAttribute("item4", ratedTitle.get(4));
         request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
         request.setAttribute("item5", ratedTitle.get(5));
         request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
         request.setAttribute("item6", ratedTitle.get(6));
         request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
         request.setAttribute("item7", ratedTitle.get(7));
         request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
         request.setAttribute("item8", ratedTitle.get(8));
         request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
         request.setAttribute("item9", ratedTitle.get(9));
         request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);

         String item1 = request.getParameter("first_item");

         String item2 = request.getParameter("second_item");

         String item3 = request.getParameter("third_item");

         String item4 = request.getParameter("fourth_item");

         String item5 = request.getParameter("fifth_item");

         String item6 = request.getParameter("sixth_item");

         String item7 = request.getParameter("seventh_item");

         String item8 = request.getParameter("eighth_item");

         String item9 = request.getParameter("ninth_item");

         String item10 = request.getParameter("tenth_item");

         ratedNumber.add(Integer.valueOf(item1));
         ratedNumber.add(Integer.valueOf(item2));
         ratedNumber.add(Integer.valueOf(item3));
         ratedNumber.add(Integer.valueOf(item4));
         ratedNumber.add(Integer.valueOf(item5));
         ratedNumber.add(Integer.valueOf(item6));
         ratedNumber.add(Integer.valueOf(item7));
         ratedNumber.add(Integer.valueOf(item8));
         ratedNumber.add(Integer.valueOf(item9));
         ratedNumber.add(Integer.valueOf(item10));
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot to show what I mean.

[image]

Comment: post your code as well .

Comment: I updated my question with the code. I'm sorry for forgetting. Thank you for reminding me.

Comment: In your code why do you have mutliple `request.getRequestDispatcher("index..` ? Also, when you load your page for the first time `getAttribute` will be `null` only because page yet didn't go to servlet.